# How can I recover my deleted messages?

Tags: sms, data-recovery, restore

I'm a symphony i110 user.unfortunatly I deleted some sms which was important.now how can I get those back?

Comment: sqlite3 just mark entries as deleted for a while until they actually deleted. get a temp root shell with [mtk-su](https://www.xda-developers.com/mediatek-su-rootkit-exploit) and pull */data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases* https://sqliteforensictoolkit.com/how-not-to-examine-sqlite-wal-files make sure you keep some untouched working copy as the files get already flushed when opening

Comment: you can also open files with HxD hex editor and search for strings you remember (it's far more easier)